# Regular expression to exclude group with 0 and more occurence issue

Tags: regex

I need to extract `1234567` from below URLs

```
http://www.test.in/some--wonders-1234567---2

http://www.test.in/some--wonders-1234567
```

I tried with `.*\-([0-9]+)(?:-{2,}2)?.`
but for the first URL it returned 2, but this is in non-capturing group.

Please give me a solution. I am digging it for so long. not getting any idea.

Comment: Which language?

Comment: What are the requirements of your match? Why should 2 *not* be included?

Comment: Would simply `\d{2,}` work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
.*?\-([0-9]+)(?:-{2,}2|$)
```

It sets lazy mode for first `.*` pattern, you can also remove it at all with same effect:

```
\-([0-9]+)(?:-{2,}2|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your regex engine supports `negative look behinds` (some do not), you can do it this way:

```
(?<!\d+-+)\d+
```

It gives you any non-empty digit string, which is **not** preceded by (minuses followed by digits).

Big advantage is that you don't have to use groups here - **regex itself** returns what you want.

Comment: How do you know the regex engine the OP is using supports lookbehinds?

Comment: Also, only a specific set of regex engines will support variable-length lookbehinds. .net and Chrome 62+'s V8 engine are some of the only (major) ones that support an infinite quantifier. Java supports non-infinite variable-length lookbehinds, so a common fix is to apply `{1,9999}` instead of `+` as a quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

You could match a `-` followed by one or more digits which you could capture in a group `([0-9]+)`. This group will contain the value you want to extract.

Then an optional part `(?:-{2,}[0-9]+)?` that would match ---2 followed by asserting the end of the line `$`.

[`-(\d+)(?:-{2,}\d+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/1lyltW/1/)

Explanation

- `-` Match literally
- `(\d+)` Capture one or more digits in a group
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `-{2,}` Match 2 or more times `-`
  - `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `)?` close non capturing group and make it optional
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line